# Adding drivers to a non bootable drive

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, waik, wim

I have a server 2008 installation with a faulty motherboard.  I have changed the motherboard and Windows blue screens on boot up.  It is caused by the SATA drivers.

I'm trying to find a method of installing the drivers manually without booting Windows.  My first idea was to create a WIM and then inject the drivers when I re-mount the image, however my new company doesn't have the windows AIK for creating WIM's.

Can anyone suggest a suitable method for adding the drivers using a 3rd party freeware or trial tool?

I have already looked at Casper and o&o.

Comment: Are you sure its the drivers? It could be the mode? The old board might have been ide and the new one will default to ahci

Comment: Hi,  Yeah i have tried IDE, AHCI and Raid.  I have narrowed it down to the exact driver and even tried manually adding the driver which involved editing about 50 registry keys.  Annoyingly i have the server 2008 r2 install disk and when i select repair my computer and then specify the drivers it errors saying that i am using a different version of windows.  I know its the correct one.

Comment: `however my new company doesnt have the windows AIK for creating WIMs` - You can just download the AIK. AFAIK, it's free and there are no licensing costs associated with using it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles onto this later on ... I'd suggest using Windows RE (either from a specifically created RE DVD  or the Windows Install DVD or via pressing F8 during Windows bootup).

When Booted up, select command prompt, and start any driver installation you got (on a USB drive for example) from there.

(see also http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4162.windows-server-2008-repair-steps-for-no-boot-issues.aspx)